# Breakpoints in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, breakpoints

problem faced in VScode is that which ever line I click on in the code
a red dot flash appears on that line

[image]

and also It seems that I cannot select the lines of text/ code with mouse

Also , when I select the text/code with keyboard, this is what happens

[image]

How to get rid of this whole breakpoint saga
any clues
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove entirely the possibility to step-debug your code, or you merely want to fix mouse selection?

Comment: find the extension that is causing this, by disabling them all first to see if it disappears.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , want to fix the mouse selection, I am currently not using debug facility at all , hence I wont mind either way

Comment: Run `code --disable-extensions` to figure out it it's caused by an extension. If so, you can use [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to identify the culprit.